# Exclude an element for its attribute in python 2.7

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to exclude the elements 'input' with the attribute 'disabled' from the list 'all_size'.

The html:

```
<div class="container">
<input id="skuAndSize__22356651:7" disabled="" />
<input id="skuAndSize__22356650:7.5" />
</div>
```

my current python code:

```
soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")
div = soup.find("div",{"class":"container"})
all_sizes = div.find_all("input")

size_in_stock = []
for size in all_sizes:
        size_id = size["id"]
        size_in_stock.append(size_id.split("__")[1])
```

Thanks for every answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a condition:

```
size_in_stock = []
for size in all_sizes:
    size_id = size["id"]
    if 'disabled' not in size.attrs:
        size_in_stock.append(size_id.split("__")[1])
```

The whole thing as list comprehension:

```
size_in_stock = [size["id"].split("__")[1] for size in all_sizes
                 if 'disabled' not in size.attrs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep Space beat me to it, so accept his answer. But just as an alternative, instead, I checked it `"disabled"` IS present, and if it is, skip and continue to next item:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="container">
<input id="skuAndSize__22356651:7" disabled="" />
<input id="skuAndSize__22356650:7.5" />
</div>'''


soup = bs(html,"html.parser")
div = soup.find("div",{"class":"container"})
all_sizes = div.find_all("input")

size_in_stock = []
for size in all_sizes:
        size_id = size["id"]
        if 'disabled' in size.attrs:
            continue
        size_in_stock.append(size_id.split("__")[1])
```